# Spring Oauth2 duplicate logins

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm using Spring Oauth2 with a custom provider and Mongo session.

When a user who is already logged in navigates to the authorization endpoint, Spring creates a new session for the user. I can see multiple duplicate sessions on mongoDB for the user.

Is there a way to prevent this?
i.e. If the user is already logged in, use the current Principal and session instead of creating a new one.

Configuration:

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/oauth2/**", "/v1/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .authorizationEndpoint()
                .baseUri("/oauth2/authorize")
                .and()
                .redirectionEndpoint()
                .baseUri("/auth/callback/*");


    }
```

Comment: What OAuth Flow you are using? 1)  Authorization Code Flow 2)Implicit Flow 3) Client Credentials Flow (Authorization Between microservices). Please provide more details about your code.

Comment: I'm using authorization code flow, most settings are the default ones. Every time I open the authorization end point for example, /oauth2/authorization/provider, I can see that a new session entry is created on mongo.

Comment: I added the security configuration code

Comment: Does each session entry create new token (JWT token). Please provide the data on the Mongo DB

Comment: @Numery here is what the mongo 'sessions' collection looks like after opening the authorization endpoint 3 times in a row: https://i.imgur.com/4O8zf36.png

Comment: @Aiden- You have to use concurrent Session Control. check the answer and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found out that this behavior is due to Spring's session fixation attack protection.

By default Spring migrates sessions on reauthentication, which makes Spring create a new session for the user by copying the existing attributes from the previous session.

When this happens however, `spring-session-data-mongodb` does not delete the old, invalidated session for some reason. I am not sure why `spring-session-data-mongodb` does not remove the old session, so if anyone has any idea on how to change this please let me know.

However, if you want to change this behavior, you can change the session fixation settings to the following to make spring use the existing session ID on reauthentication:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 http.sessionManagement().sessionFixation().none()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable or control the session in this case.

```
always – a session will always be created if one 
doesn't already exist

ifRequired – a session will be created only if 
required (default)

never – the framework will never create a 
session itself but it will use one if it already 
exists

stateless – no session will be created or used 
by Spring Security
```

Java configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) 
throws Exception {
   http.sessionManagement()
     .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
}
```

4. Concurrent Session Control--

When a user that is already authenticated tries to authenticate again, the application can deal with that event in one of a few ways. It can either invalidate the active session of the user and authenticate the user again with a new session, or allow both sessions to exist concurrently.

The first step in enabling the concurrent session-control support is to add the following listener in the web.xml:

```
<listener>
 <listener-class>
   org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
 </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Or define it as a Bean – as follows:

```
@Bean
public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
   return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
}
```

This is essential to make sure that the Spring Security session registry is notified when the session is destroyed.

To enable the scenario which allows multiple concurrent sessions for the same user the  element should be used in the XML configuration:

```
<http ...>
 <session-management>
    <concurrency-control max-sessions="2" />
 </session-management>
</http>
```

Or, via Java configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(2)
}
```

Please have a look the following link --
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session

Comment: I added the settings you mentioned but still getting multiple entries on mongo. I believe this might be an issue with the spring-session-data-mongodb rather than spring security. I believe the sessions are invalidated and new session is created but the entries on mongo are not getting removed.

Comment: The reason I assume this is because I tried changing the value of the principal field on all documents and once I logged in again, the value of the principal was set to the correct value on all mongo documents.

Comment: Aiden- Thanks a lot for your update. Can you change the database to mysql and update us. It will be helpful for lots of people.

Comment: I will try that. One more thing, I tried changing the sessionCreationPolicy to NEVER and I'm still seeing the same behavior which seems strange.

Comment: Aiden- Concurrent Session on mysql is working fine on my end. But I am not sure about mongodb. Please update us about your research. Thanks

Comment: After some research I found a solution. Please check the answer I posted.